# what is "internet protocol, pseudo protocol number"?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming, network-protocols, raw-sockets

I am using raw socket to capture network packets. I captured Ethernet header and then I accessed IP header and in IP header, there is a field of 'protocol'. I printed this field and compare with values present in /etc/protocols. I have received '0' value that means-

```
ip   0    IP     #'internet protocol, pseudo protocol number'
```

That means IP header contains protocol that is also IP. What does that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [**Protocol Numbers**](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) this is the protocol *IPv6 Hop-by-Hop Option* [[RFC2460](http://www.iana.org/go/rfc2460)].